# Debug changes other code. Corona SDK

Tags: assembly, lua, coronasdk

In Corona SDK I'm making an application where a player can drive a car. I have a print function that is called when the car gets an impulse.

```
print("@",self.frames,virtual,self.animation.rotation,self.animation.angularDamping);
```

About 60 times per second. When it's uncommented the car control becomes much more sensitive. It seems to me that it is caused by overspending system resources on debug.

I want to leave the side effect of print(), but not to waste CPU on it. If you know what does Corona Simulator at low-level code when I try to put too many actions in one frame, could you explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are correct with the assumption that you are taxing system resources.

Maybe you could achieve a similar effect by lowering the frame rate (if you are using a runtime function). That seems like a workaround to whatever your real problem is. Instead of using a runtime function, you could also use a game loop timer that is called 30 times a second or so, and adjust that accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a table that will contain all debugging data. Then you can put a timer that will print your data every x seconds to the terminal or you can write it to a file.

```
data = {}

function onEveryFrame()

    data[#data + 1] = { }
    data.frames = self.frames
    data.virtual = virtual
    data.rotation = self.animation.angularDamping
    data.angularDamping = self.animation.angularDamping

end

function calledByTimerEveryXSeconds()

// print data table here

end
```